# [Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘/home/robot/catkin_ws/build’

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I solve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403481/%5Berrno-13%5D-permission-denied:-%E2%80%98/home/robot/catkin_ws/build%E2%80%99/) by [SRY7](https://answers.ros.org/users/109541/sry7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it. Change permission and ownership of the catkin workspace directory:

- sudo chown user:user -R /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/
- sudo chown user:user -R /home/user/catkin_ws/src/
- sudo chown user:user -R /home/user/catkin_ws/build/

---

Originally posted by [SRY7](https://answers.ros.org/users/109541/sry7/) with karma: 16 on 2022-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0